# Escape Codes/Random characters in JSch ssh response

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsch

I am using JSch to ssh to a Linux server and run a custom utility and checking response in java code. I see some random characters in response. The same looks fine while checking in Putty.

```
private String logResponse(Channel channel, InputStream in) throws IOException {
    byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    while (true) {
        while (in.available() > 0) {
            int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
            if (i < 0)
                break;
            return new String(tmp, 0, i);
        }
        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Printing the response using above method (erased some texts) [image: Screenshot of eclipse console]

If it is used in subsequent methods or printed in files, it will display different random characters.
[image]

Could it be due to encoding? Kindly suggest if the above method can be tweaked. Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like escape codes.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thank you for the suggestions. I am using exec channel and there are prompts as well. Added a regex to replace escape codes and it is now readable.

`text.replaceAll("(\\x9B|\\x1B\\[)[0-?]*[ -\\/]*[@-~]", "");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using exec channel and there are prompts as well. Added a regex to replace escape codes and it is now readable.

```
text.replaceAll("(\\x9B|\\x1B\\[)[0-?]*[ -\\/]*[@-~]", "");
```